# php json_decode VS Laravel Tinker json_decode

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have a problem about php json_decode, now i have a json string like this

```
"{\"client_id\":\"yunniao\",\"client_secret\":\"sdfW234eDtjkuDFityDu345JYyuk5Jom\",\"insurance_applicant_id\":1,\"policyholder\":\"\\u5317\\u4eac\\u4e91\\u4e2d\\u5c0f\\u9e1f\\u79d1\\u6280\\u6709\\u9650\\u516c\\u53f8\",\"ower_name\":\"\\u8bd7\\u6768\\u8fd0\\u529b\\u4e8c\",\"plate_no\":\"\\u4eacM00002\",\"trade_no\":\"2932848\",\"cargo_type\":\"\\u4e34\\u65f6\\u4efb\\u52a1-\\u6709SOP\",\"cargo_amount\":\"1-1\",\"cargo_number_min\":1,\"cargo_number_max\":1,\"start_place\":\"\\u5367\\u9f99\\u5c0f\\u533a\",\"end_place\":\"\\u4e3b\\u4efb\\u52a1-\\u6709SOP\",\"effect_date\":\"2017-07-01T00:08:44+08:00\",\"coverage\":100000,\"freight\":\"3000\"}"
```

is a very json string,;

- i put this in `Laravel artisan tiker` the above string return me like this, it's a image, but it's not show in here:

  [image]
- but in the php interactive command line, the json string give me nothing, the result like behind image;

  [image]

**i'm tried a lot of possibilities;**

> 1. i tried to put above code in my Laravel project, then test the file, it give me `null`;
> 2. i googled so many times, but there is no answer;

it's all failed, now i'm here, i think i want help! 
**thanks for any help and workround.**

===================================================================

**Hello guys, i have been resolved this, i used `eval`, the eval like this**

```
$param = "{\"insurance_applicant_id\":1,\"plate_no\":\"\\u4eacA11113\",\"trade_no\":86254,\"cargo_type\":\"\",\"cargo_number_min\":0,\"cargo_number_max\":0,\"cargo_amount\":\"0~0\",\"start_place\":\"\\u897f\\u82d1\",\"end_place\":\"\\u914d\\u9001\\u533a\\u57df\\u63cf\\u8ff0\",\"effect_date\":\"2016-01-09 14:54:04\",\"coverage\":0,\"freight\":79200}";
eval("\$param = \"$param\";");
$decodeValue = json_decode($param);
```

hope this help for other people, i closed this, **thanks everybody again!**

Answer (score 0):

The interactive PHP console simply does not automatically output the value of the last evaluated expression. Your PHP code doesn't `echo` anything, so there's no output. You need to `print_r(json_decode(...))` to see something.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but it's give me nothing, nothing is not come A `null`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$json = "{\"client_id\":\"yunniao\",\"client_secret\":\"sdfW234eDtjkuDFityDu345JYyuk5Jom\",\"insurance_applicant_id\":1,\"policyholder\":\"\\u5317\\u4eac\\u4e91\\u4e2d\\u5c0f\\u9e1f\\u79d1\\u6280\\u6709\\u9650\\u516c\\u53f8\",\"ower_name\":\"\\u8bd7\\u6768\\u8fd0\\u529b\\u4e8c\",\"plate_no\":\"\\u4eacM00002\",\"trade_no\":\"2932848\",\"cargo_type\":\"\\u4e34\\u65f6\\u4efb\\u52a1-\\u6709SOP\",\"cargo_amount\":\"1-1\",\"cargo_number_min\":1,\"cargo_number_max\":1,\"start_place\":\"\\u5367\\u9f99\\u5c0f\\u533a\",\"end_place\":\"\\u4e3b\\u4efb\\u52a1-\\u6709SOP\",\"effect_date\":\"2017-07-01T00:08:44+08:00\",\"coverage\":100000,\"freight\":\"3000\"}";
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
```

It will give you decoded json in array form like this

```
[
 "client_id" => "yunniao",
 "client_secret" => "sdfW234eDtjkuDFityDu345JYyuk5Jom",
 "insurance_applicant_id" => 1,
 "policyholder" => "σîùΣ║¼Σ║æΣ╕¡σ░ÅΘ╕ƒτºæµèÇµ£ëΘÖÉσà¼σÅ╕",
 "ower_name" => "Φ»ùµ¥¿Φ┐Éσè¢Σ║î",
 "plate_no" => "Σ║¼M00002",
 "trade_no" => "2932848",
 "cargo_type" => "Σ╕┤µù╢Σ╗╗σèí-µ£ëSOP",
 "cargo_amount" => "1-1",
 "cargo_number_min" => 1,
 "cargo_number_max" => 1,
 "start_place" => "σìºΘ╛Öσ░Åσî║",
 "end_place" => "Σ╕╗Σ╗╗σèí-µ£ëSOP",
 "effect_date" => "2017-07-01T00:08:44+08:00",
 "coverage" => 100000,
 "freight" => "3000",
]
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i want to know what's enviornment you used? in my php interactive command line it's return me nothing event if i copy your code in CLI.